# How to create large 3D array in Python/Numpy from coordinates and values

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like to create 3D array of points, where I have list of three coordinates (x,y,z) and value at this coordinate. I have 6308 points of measurement.
For reference, I pasted the data in the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/JadFRpCs). The purpose is to create 3D Numpy array and calculate 3D Fourier transform.

I would like to arrange this data into 3D array. I tried to use [xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/) module for this - but the [xarray.DataArray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.html) needs  numpy.ndarray as its input.

I tried to create meshgrid and put data value into coordinates but I had MemoryError.

Finally, I tried to make test random array:

```
out = np.zeros(shape=(6308,6308,6308))
```

but I also had the error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.83 TiB for an array with shape (6308, 6308, 6308) and data type float64
```

And at this point I don't have any idea how to arrange the data into 3D array for 3D Fourier transform calculation. Is it even possible?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using am array of size [1, 3, 6308]? That would have 3 values per point, and 6308 points

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine this shape of array. But my purpose was to use [scipy.fft.fftn](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fftn.html) for 3D array. Probably in this shape which You suggest I'm not able to calculate 3D FFT. I'm not sure I need to think and learn something more. BTW, thanks for suggestion

Comment: I can't imagine that [6038, 6038, 6038] would correspond to the points you want. That's a lot more than just 6308. That corresponds to 6038 separate matrices, with 6038 columns, and 6038 rows per column. You'd want one matrix, with 3 columns, and 6038 rows. That way, the (X, Y, Z) coordinates would fit in each column, and each row would be a separate point.

Comment: I'm thinking about Your suggestion, thank You.
But what I'm able to understand - for example, there a cube of dimension 10x10x10 with values at each coordinate when x=y=z. For example:
 xx = np.arange(10)
yy = np.arange(10)
zz = np.arange(10)
vv = np.linspace(15,150,10)

Even I'am able to plot the data as 3D grid:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xx,yy,zz,s=vv,c=xx)
But when I try to create 3D array I can make follwing:
a3d = np.zeros((1,3,10))
a3d[0,0,:] = xx
a3d[0,1,:] = yy
a3d[0,2,:] = zz
So in a3d I have the coords. But what with values?